# Excel DateTime is a string how can I convert to real datetime C#?

Tags: c#, excel, visual-studio, date, datetime

The way my excel is formatted when programming in C# and I pull the cell with the supposed date I get a string "44165". On Excel it shows as a date. I need to convert this to DateTime to do something else. The string is equal to 2021-11-30 when I put it in excel and convert the column to datetime. However when I try to convert to DateTime in C# I get the error "String was not recognized as a valid Datetime".

The value is read using :

```
cell.CellValue.InnerXml
```

I have tried

```
Convert.ToDateTime,
DateTime.Parse,
DateTime.ParseExact
```

None of which work and always result in "String was not recognized as a valid Datetime".
I cannot change the formatting of the excel I must find a solution within visual studio using C#.

I highly appreciate any help, thanks.

Comment: Excel dates are *not* strings. The actual storage format is a 64-bit float in the OADate format. How did you read the data? Excel libraries expose that number as a proper `DateTime`. If you read the raw value you can convert it to a DateTime with `DateTime.FromOADate` but you *shouldn't have to*

Comment: Please post your code. Which library did you use to read the Excel file? How did you read that value? Somehow the code read the date as a `double` and converted it to a string.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I can't post the code but the value is read in by cell.CellValue.InnerXml

Comment: Which means you're using the very low level OpenXML SDK to read the raw values. It's up to you to parse these values based on the cell's style and attributes. A far better idea is to let a library like ExcelDataReader do this for you. You already added one additional library, why not use a better one?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I used DateTime.FromOADate(Convert.ToDouble(cellstring)) and it is working as expected. Thank you for the help

Comment: That's the workaround. Why not let a different library do the job?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
double myOADate = 44165;
DateTime myDate = DateTime.FromOADate(myOADate);

Console.WriteLine(myDate.ToString());
```

The above returns

30/11/2020 00:00:00